# How to implement a weight measurement scale in react-native?

Tags: react-native, expo, nativewind

[image: This is my weight measurement view]

I am new to react-native. I am trying to create a fitness app. While creating the profile, I am asking for weight to input. Our UI will look like the above image.
But I have no idea, How I can implement this UI. Please, can someone advise me on how to implement this UI? 
(For example: **Which library can I use? What is the idea behind this?**)
Note: I am using expo to build the app.